# Docker container can't call localhost inside container itself

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose environment setup.
But inside service "Lumen" im trying to make a CURL request to the service itself.

However, the container can't access itself from localhost:8000 OR lumen:8000??

When I call lumen:8000 from the service it just never returns a response and just keeps loading ( And the curl request is to a different url so no infinite loop )

In my Laravel controller I found the protocal, host and port to be: http://lumen:8000

I seems like Laravel can't connect to itself, which I really need for my project.

I can connect to the Laravel from my own computer through localhost, but I need the Laravel to call it self.

Error message from Laravel controller after doing a CURL request:
`Failed to connect to localhost port 8000 after 0 ms: Connection refused`
Changing host to "lumen" just makes the request load infinite. No matter what page I try to connect to.

Docker-compose file:

```ml
version: "3.5"

services:
  lumen:
    expose: 
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/html
      - ./server/vendor:/var/www/html/vendor/
    build: 
      context: server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: php -S lumen:8000 -t public
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - database

  frontend:
    build:
      context: client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client/src:/app/src
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    #restart: always
    networks:
      - database

  # Database Service (Mysql)
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: blogmoda_mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blogmoda-app
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci','--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - database

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - database
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    networks:
      - database

volumes:
  db-data:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  database:
```

Server dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash

RUN apk add chromium

RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

COPY . .

RUN composer install --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `localhost` should work.  Assuming curl is installed in `lumen`, in your compose file under the `lumen` service can you try changing your command

```
command: php -S lumen:8000 -t public
```

to a direct curl via bash as

```
command: sh -c "curl -s localhost:8000"
```

Then check the logs of the `lumen` container to see whether or not the curl ran successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Curl does work for every other url, but localhost:8000 does not work inside the container ( Which it should )

With your code I get "blogmoda-app-php_lumen_1 exited with code 7" ( I think it because you don't run the lumen service at port 8000

I have updated the post with the lumen dockerfile, I don't know if its the container setup or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try `0.0.0.0:8000` instead `localhost:8000`. It works for localhost too

Comment: Try 0.0.0.:8000 where? Please be more specific.

Comment: Here.`command: php -S localhost:8000 -t public` change to  `command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a cURL request from within a PHP script running in a Docker container to a service running on localhost inside the same Docker container, you should use the Docker container's IP address instead of `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`. This is because each Docker container has its own isolated network namespace, and `localhost` refers to the container itself, not the host machine.

Here's how you can modify your cURL request to use the Docker container's IP address:

```php
<?php
// API endpoint URL
$url = 'http://<container_ip>/api/order-status'; // Replace <container_ip> with the IP address of your Docker container

// Replace with your actual API key
$api_key = '12345690MdeSD';

// Data to be sent in the request body
$data = array(
    'order_id' => $orderId, // assuming $orderId is defined elsewhere
    'status_id' => $statusId // assuming $statusId is defined elsewhere
);

// Encode data as JSON
$data_json = json_encode($data);

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Api-Key: ' . $api_key
));

// Execute cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // Print response
    echo $response;
}

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Replace `<container_ip>` with the actual IP address of your Docker container. You can find this IP address by running `docker inspect <container_name>` or `docker inspect <container_id>`, depending on how you named or identified your container. Look for the `"IPAddress"` field in the output. Use that IP address in place of `<container_ip>` in the `$url` variable.